# アカウントを削除するとどうなりますか？

Tags: サポート, アカウント

退会する気はないんですけど、ちょっと気になったのでお伺いしてもよろしいでしょうか。

アカウントの削除をした場合、どのようなことが起こるのでしょうか？

１．そのアカウントを使用してログインができなくなる。
２．自分が獲得した信用度やバッジはすべてなくなる。
３．ユーザー名は消えて、ピクチャが非常口マンになる。

他にどういったことへ影響しますか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 他に起こりうること

- マイナス点の投稿は削除されることがあります。
- 他のユーザーの信用度に影響する場合があります。

#### 関連

全て Stack Exchange Meta 上へのリンクです。

- [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/341401)
- [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740/341401)
- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/341401)